# И снова про перебор массива (php)

Tags: php, массивы

В старом варианте кода элемент находился только в одном разделе. Массив перебирался и если id раздела в элементе совпадал с id раздела (section), элемент добавлялся к массиву с сортировкой по секциям :

```
foreach ($sections as &$section){
            foreach ($elements as $element){
                if ($section["ID"] == $element["IBLOCK_SECTION_ID"]){
                    $section["elements"][] = $element;
                }
            }
        }
```

Затем логика поменялась и элемент теперь может находится сразу в нескольких разделах одновременно. В массив элементов я добавил новую переменную: `$element["GROUPS"]` которая содержит массив с несколькими id разделов следующего вида:

```
["GROUPS"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "83"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "150"
  }
```

Вопрос как мне добавить в массив `$section["elements"][]` элементы совпадающие по id из массива `$element["GROUPS"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понял, Вы хотите добавлять в секции те элементы, у которых массив GROUPS содержит ID секции-принимающего, верно? В таком случае я могу посоветовать использовать метод [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php):

```php
foreach ($sections as &$section){
            foreach ($elements as $element){
                if (in_array($section["ID"], $element["GROUPS"])) {
                    $section["elements"][] = $element;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, оптимальное решение, я уж было хотел следующим уровнем вложенности перебирать массив массив GROUPS, но было ощущение, что есть более правильное решение.